# What are the provisions to use Observer in free version of an extension in Magento 2 standards?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I want to built an extension for magento 2 community version which allows me to get product data. Can I able to use Observer? I heard that magento commerce (magento connect - marketplace) will not allow extension which uses observer?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Could you explain in more depth?

Comment: @RyanHoerr, sorry for the confusion. I just modified my query.

Answer (score 0):

Observers are a part of the Magento2 core framework. Plugins are preferred where possible, but there are perfectly legitimate use cases for using observers as well. There is no restriction against using them in either the Magento code standards or for submissions to the Magento Marketplace.

Use them however you need to.